# undefined method `find_or_create'

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to upsert record in database using following command

```
Profile.find_or_create(fname: contact.FirstName, lname: contact.LastName,
  company: account.Name, title: contact.Title, user_id: contact.CreatedById, 
  account_id: account.Id, contact_id: contact.Id, type: "contact"  )
```

where `Profile` is an `activerecord model`

but I get following error

```
undefined method find_or_create for Profile class
```

`Profile.public_methods` doesn't show `find_or_create` method but `Activerecord Api` defines the above method.

What might be wrong?

Comment: you're using a rails 4 version of the method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

its `find_or_create_by` and its deprecated in Rails 3.

use `@foo = Foo.find_by_bar("baz") || Foo.create(:bar => "baz")`

Comment: I don't think this is quite true. `find_or_create_by` isn't deprecated. It's the related dynamically generated methods like `find_or_create_by_bar` that are deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [**`Rails 4 docs`**](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) use:

```
User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Joe')
```

instead of:

```
User.find_or_create_by_first_name('Joe')
```

Answer (score 1):

My Rails version

```
Rails -v
  Rails 3.1.3
```

My Ruby Version

```
Ruby -v
  ruby 1.9.2p290
```

In Rails console I am able to use the

```
find_or_create_by method like below

1.9.2-p290 :001 > User.find_or_create_by_name("soundar")
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'soundar' LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, name: "soundar", age: 23, created_at: "2012-04-17 11:12:43", updated_at: "2012-04-17 11:12:43">
```

Comment: You need to use Model.find_or_create_by_field(attributes_hash).But you have used find_or_create which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

~> Rails 4

```
["Goose Island IPA", "Dogfish Head 90 Min IPA", "Mother Earth Oatmeal Stout", "Raleigh Brewing Mocha Stout"].each do |beer|
  Beer.find_or_initialize_by(name: beer)
end
```